# iOS push notification iBeacon Estimote

Tags: android, ios, push-notification, ibeacon, estimote

I am currently working on iBeacons on Android.

Here my devices :

Estimote Beacon

I came across asking myself a question, here is it :

**Can "push notification" be pushed on iOS without any third parties applications ?**

Just to clear out : I want to be sure if weither or not it's possible with the iOS core.

Sincerly yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On iOS there are both *Push Notifications* (which are generated server-side and are transported by an Apple service) and *Local Notifications*, which originate on the device itself, often as a result of a sensor trigger like an iBeacon.  Generally it is *Local Notifications* that are triggered by a beacon.

You can trigger a Local Notification on iOS with a beacon, but **a third party app is required** to fire the notification as a result of seeing a beacon.  It is not possible without a third party app.

Comment: Ok thanks for clearing this out.I wasn't sure even then tought I googled it.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to vote on your answer. But it's the one I was expecting.

Comment: Glad this helped.  If you believe this answers your question you can accept the answer without needing any reputation.  Accepting an answer helps others find solutions to similar questions.

Comment: I was looking for the button to mark as answered all around tought. It just needs to be checked, my bad -_-'. Have a good day.